# JDE BSFN error while calling from java servlet

Tags: java, jdedwards

I am trying to call the JDE "Approve Or Reject Order" business function from a java servlet. We are passing all the values correctly from java side(making all necessary conversions to map the jde math numeric , date and branch plant parameters). However, the business function call is getting failed.The error is attached.[JDE BSFN Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1LZM.jpg)